# Trying to get a property of a non-object

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have the following snippet of code that should return the contents of a post.

My View:

```
 @foreach($posts as $post)
 <h2 class="post-title"> {{$post->title}} </h2>
 <p> {{ $post->content_posts()->first()}} </p>
 @endforeach
```

This return the ENTIRE object,

As soon as you only want the content (or any other attribute) part of the object it throws "Trying to get a property of a non-object" error

The View that has the error:

```
 @foreach($posts as $post)
 <h2 class="post-title"> {{$post->title}} </h2>
 <p> {{ $post->content_posts()->first()->content}} </p>
 @endforeach
```

The Controller looks as follows:

```
    public function getAllPost(){   
    $posts = Post::all();
    return View::make('posts.allposts', ['posts' => $posts]);}
```

The Model relationship are as follows:

This is the Post model:

```
    public function content_posts(){
    return $this-> hasMany('ContentPost');}
```

The ContentPost model:

```
    public function post(){
    return $this-> belongsTo('Post');}
```

Is there a mistake somewhere in my Model, Controller or in the View?

Comment: Does $post->content_posts have any data. I.e. is there any information within your database. If there is no data, then a null will be returned, and you are trying to access a property on a null object. Check there is data in $post->content_posts()->first() before you do $post->content_posts()->first()->content.

Comment: Hi @MattBurrow, there is data in the table, if I run the first snippet of code it returns the following: {"id":"1","post_id":"1","content":"Some contents here ","file_upload":"","created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"}

Comment: _"Trying to get a property of a non-object"_ commonly appear because the variable is `NULL`. The `$posts` in your view is not NULL ?

Comment: Could you try using $post->content_posts()->first()['content']? Just asking as sometimes i get an array when i should get a model object.

Comment: @Debflav as in the comment above there is some data in $posts, but as soon as you only want only one field, it gives the error. Is there something that you can suggest?

Comment: @MattBurrow WHAT A LEGEND!!! Thanks allot!!! Just solved the issue I had the last two days.

Comment: @escGoat007 added as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using;

```
$post->content_posts()->first()['content']
```

Make sure to check for the data $post->content_posts()->first()  before you display what you want to prevent this error from occurring again.